# Openvas 9 - Continual logouts due to "Server reached connection limit (closing inbound connection)"

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, openvas, gsa

I keep having issues with getting logged out of Openvas/Greenbone Security Assistant, and after monitoring the logs while I was trying to run a scan, I finally noticed these lines that corresponded with when I had to reauthenticate:

```
gsad main:WARNING:2018-03-07 20h15.30 UTC:208: MHD: Server reached connection limit (closing inbound connection)
gsad main:WARNING:2018-03-07 20h15.30 UTC:208: MHD: Server reached connection limit (closing inbound connection)
gsad main:WARNING:2018-03-07 20h15.31 UTC:208: MHD: Server reached connection limit (closing inbound connection)
```

My timeout setting in `/etc/default/openvas-gsa` is 60 minutes, but because of that connection limit it's not respecting it.

**Is there a config option to increase that connection limit so I don't get logged out until the timeout setting kicks in?** OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4, I installed OpenVAS from [this](https://launchpad.net/~mrazavi/+archive/ubuntu/openvas) repo inside a vanilla Ubuntu LXC image.

**EDIT**: According to [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libmicrohttpd/2010-04/msg00006.html) it looks like theres a config option for `libmicrohttpd`, I'll try messing with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found the answer after all this time, the `gsad` daemon reads `microhttpd` settings from `/usr/include/microhttpd.h`, so when I bump up `MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_LIMIT` (line 1215 - https://gnunet.org/git/libmicrohttpd.git/tree/src/include/microhttpd.h#n1215) to something more reasonable than the default of 2, gsad allows more concurrent connections.

Since I'm using an nginx reverse proxy in front of it, having a really low setting for that would always cause a bunch of HTTP 502s whenever I would login to GSA to do anything.